# How to see the file system in Docker image used in Gitlab pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I am new to Dockers and Gitlab pipeline. There is something that I have hard time to understand.
This is how my gitlab-ci.yml looks like:

```
stages:
  - test

testing:
  stage: test
  image: ubuntu
  when: manual
  script:
    - ls
```

My expectation for "ls" command is to see the file system of the ubuntu container, but instead of it I see my project files. Is it a normal situation?

Comment: try to put `ls /` as your script. What do you see?

Comment: Just to let you understand what's happening when you do just `ls`. when GitLab runs your docker image it will mount your project files into the container and set that as the working dir. So when the container starts it will be in your project dir which has been mounted into the continer